# Adding spaces and characters to existing text within a text file

Tags: c#

I would like to improve my program by editing an existing text file after the initial code has been run.

Current Code:

```
private string file_path = @"Tags.txt";

public txtEditor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

//PROCEDURE
private void Procedure()
{
    // READ AND APPEND LINES
    File.WriteAllLines(file_path, File.ReadAllLines(file_path).Where(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "NE 1:") || (Regex.IsMatch(line, "NE 2:"))));
}

private void btnRefine_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Procedure();
}
```

The result of running the code changes the text file to look like this:

```
LINE 1: hello
LINE 2: hello
LINE 1: hello
LINE 2: hello
LINE 1: hello
LINE 2: hello
```

- From here, I would like to add spaces and angle brackets to the existing text as shown below.
- The word 'hello' is an example of random text that is different on each tag.

```
LINE 1: <hello
LINE 2: hello>

LINE 1: <hello
LINE 2: hello>

LINE 1: <hello
LINE 2: hello>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couple questions: 1. what is the .txt file is comprised of? 2.  Is the program rendering the same two lines 3 times, or is it 6 identical lines? 3. is the content the same for the line 1 as line 2?

Comment: What is the rule of when to add brackets?

Comment: So the text file consists of any number of tags and one tag is made up of 'LINE 1:' AND 'LINE 2:' etc. Before the text file has been refined, it has a bunch of irrelevant info between each tag. I would just like to add a space between each tag to separate them

Comment: The purpose of the angle brackets are to enclose the tag text, so the printer knows what to print. IN this case, the first bracket will be placed before the text on the first line and the second bracket will be placed at the end of line 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var str = @"LINE 1: hello
LINE 2: hello
LINE 1: hello
LINE 2: hello
LINE 1: hello
LINE 2: hello";
        var arr = str.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string[] arr2 = new string[arr.Count()];
        bool pair = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (pair)
            {
                var index = arr[i].Length;
                arr2[i] = arr[i].Insert(index, ">\r\n");
                pair = !pair;
            }
            else
            {
                arr2[i] = arr[i].Insert(8, "<");
                pair = !pair;
            }
        }
        string modString = "";
        foreach (var item in arr2)
        {
            modString += item + "\r\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(modString);
```